# Weird Date issue

Tags: java, jodatime

Running the following method as a test on its own class

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1942, 11, 16, 1, 0, 0);
System.out.println(dt.getChronology().getZone().getID());
System.out.println(dt);
System.out.println(dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")));
System.out.println(dt.toDate());
```

gives the output:

```
    Europe/London
    1942-11-16T01:00:00.000+01:00
    1942-11-16T01:00:00.000+01:00
    Mon Nov 16 01:00:00 BST 1942
```

However, running *all* tests, which includes the above method, results in:

```
    Europe/London
    1942-11-16T01:00:00.000+01:00
    1942-11-16T01:00:00.000+01:00
    Mon Nov 16 00:00:00 BDT 1942
```

I'm at a bit of a loss how to explain this behaviour... My system timezone is definitely not changing between the two kinds of test execution.....

(This is an issue as this also *sometimes* but not reproducibly occurs when manipulating `java.util.Date`)

Comment: i'd usually use [nodatime](http://nodatime.org/), but could you step through it and see the creation, and what it brings?

Comment: can you please show the *complete* code that reproduces this issue

Comment: @jbutler483: You'd have a hard time doing that in Java :)

Comment: BDT??? You meant to say BST right? Cause BDT is Bangladesh Time.....hope this is a typo?

Comment: @JonSkeet: hello! But my comment had posted before i'd finished typing, so hence it read in the wrong way :L

Comment: I would suggest removing one test at a time until you've found which tests are required to demonstrate the problem. Then post all the relevant code. My guess is that *something* is changing the time zone data...

Comment: @reto This *is* the complete code that produces the issue.

Comment: @hagubear ... I know ... This is the problem.

Comment: No, this is clearly *not* the complete code that produces the issue, as you need to run it in conjunction with other tests in order to get the different output. (I'm looking forward to seeing complete code that I *can* just copy, paste, compile and run though... it'll be interesting to see where this comes from.)

Comment: @user2482461       Could you please put the test code here? I assume you are using some form of JUnit tests? Nevertheless, we cannot attempt any reproduction of the problem if the tests aren't here.

Comment: Also, just to check, are you sure it's just BDT rather than BDST? I could *nearly* understand the latter...

Comment: @hagubear there are thousands of other tests.. :(

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes :( I've copied and pasted exact output

Comment: Right, so start stripping out the tests in large swathes. Basically do a binary chop - remove *half* the tests and see whether that changes the output. If it does, put them back and remove the other half, etc. There's clearly a lot of code running other than the code you've shown us - some part of that code is relevant, but we can't tell what.

Comment: what version of jodatime are you using? Have you tried a newer one?

Comment: @user2482461        Okay but you still need to supply the following metrics - How many tests, how long does it take you to complete the test suite and if you are fiddling with the locale in any of your tests.

Comment: I would try to put a breakpoint on `TimeZone.setDefault` and run all tests. Good chance it will break and you'll have your culprit.

Comment: Make some calls to [`TimeZone::getDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--) to verify the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the default timezone was being explicitly set in a part of the code that used timezones. As a result, every other call that used the default JVM timezone would use this new timezone - resulting in the differences described.

Answer (score 1):

In order to work properly with dates, you should always specify the time zone when you create a date.
If you do this way, you won't get strange results.